# Is there a Chrome extension that will replace the default Chrome Download Manager?

Tags: windows-vista, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

The default Chrome download manager does not resume downloads when Chrome is restarted. When a file is being downloaded, or paused before it is completly downloaded, closing Chrome 12.0.742.112 shows the following dialog.

[image]

Is there an extension for Chrome that can replace the default Download Manager so that it'll allow downloads to resume even after chrome is restarted? Please note that I am not looking for a software to install on the OS that will integrate with Chrome and capture all its downloads. The solution should be a google chrome extension. (*.crx file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there an extension for Chrome that can replace the default Download Manager so that it'll allow downloads to resume even after chrome is restarted?
>
> **Please note that I am not looking for a software to install on the OS**

No, there is no such extension which can do this.

Comment: Thanks. I'll leave this open for some more just to be sure and then accept the answer.

Comment: Sure thing, @Thomas.